# The data of my Global class becomes null if I start my display activity (android)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a service which fetches a response from Net and displays it in a notification.
The problem is that when the service puts the response in a variable global to my activity the variable become null. But if I put the response in the intent extra, its value changes.
Here is my code.

Here the service fetches and stores response on a list of Article. mArticles is an ArrayList and mArticle is simply an instance of Article. (Here mArticle and mArticles were not null, I test it with Log.)

```
private void showNotification(){

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_notification, mTitle, System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    final Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, ArticleActivity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra(ListFragmentBase.NUMBER, Utils.LA_UNE);
    myIntent.putExtra(ListFragmentBase.SOURCE_COMPONENT, Utils.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    myIntent.putExtra(ARTICLE_NOTIF, mArticle);
    myIntent.putExtra(ListFragmentBase.POSITION, 0);
    GlobalStateArticle glo = (GlobalStateArticle)getApplication();
    glo.setArticles(mArticles);
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, mTitle, mContent, pending);
    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    notifManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Here is a portion of my activity where I want to display response when the notification is clicked. The problem is located here. mArticles is null here, intent.getParcelableExtra is not null but its contents change.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int number = intent.getIntExtra(ListFragmentBase.NUMBER, 1);
    int source = intent.getIntExtra(ListFragmentBase.SOURCE_COMPONENT, -1);
    String title = intent.getStringExtra(ListFragmentBase.TITLE);
    switch(number){
    case Utils.CULTURE:
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Bayiri_culture);
    break;
    case Utils.DIASPORA:
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Bayiri_diaspora);
    break;
    case Utils.DIVERTISSEMENT:
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Bayiri_divertissement);
    break;
    case Utils.ECONOMIE:
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Bayiri_economie);
    break;
    case Utils.EDUCATION:
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Bayiri_education);
    break;
    case Utils.INTERNATIONAL:
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Bayiri_international);
    break;
    case Utils.LA_UNE:
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Bayiri_une);
    break;
    case Utils.POLITIQUE:
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Bayiri_politique);
    break;
    case Utils.SOCIETE:
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Bayiri_societe);
    break;
    case Utils.SPORT:
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Bayiri_sport);
    break;
    case Utils.TECH:
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Bayiri_tech);
    break;
    default:
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Bayiri_une);
    break;
    }
    Utils.setupActionBar(this, topView, number);
    setContentView(R.layout.article_activity);
    mAdView = (PublisherAdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD){
        PublisherAdRequest adRequest = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }else ((ViewGroup)mAdView.getParent()).removeView(mAdView);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    if(source == Utils.LIST_ARTICLE_ACTIVITY){
        GlobalsArticles g = GlobalsArticles.getInstance();
        mArticles = g.getData();
    }else if(source == Utils.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE){
        /*Article a = intent.getParcelableExtra(NotificationService.ARTICLE_NOTIF);
        mArticles = new ArrayList<Article>();
        mArticles.add(a);*/
        GlobalStateArticle glo = (GlobalStateArticle)getApplication();
        mArticles = glo.getArticles();
        Log.d("message", String.valueOf(mArticles == null));
    }
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    boolean swipeOk = pref.getBoolean("pref_swipe", true);
    mArticlePagerAdapter = new ArticlePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mArticles);
    int current = intent.getIntExtra(ListFragmentBase.POSITION, 0);
    mPager = (MyViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    if(mPager != null){
        mPager.setPagingEnabled(swipeOk);
        mPager.setAdapter(mArticlePagerAdapter);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(current);
        mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }
}
```

So if I use the intent.getParcelableExtra I get sometimes different result and if I use GlobalStateArticle I get a NullPointerException when the notification is clicked.

Comment: What is the type of mArticle? Is it Parcelable, and correctly implemented?

Comment: Yes @matiash it is parcelable. In another part of my code i use it with success

Comment: Does ArticleActivity have `launchMode` `singleTop` or `singleTask`?

Comment: The lauchMode of ArticleActivity is the default. I dont't define this attribute